# Assigning ipv6 addresses for multiple ipv6 only proxies

Tags: linux, routing, proxy, ipv6

I'm a bit new to IPV6, so please correct me if I have some horrible misunderstanding somewhere.

I have a situation where I want to run multiple ipv6 only proxies on Linux (Ubuntu 18.04 and proxies would not be visible from outside the firewall).  I'd like each of my proxy servers to get a different ipv6 address from within the address space my ISP/router provides.

That is, I have a /64 prefix provided by my ISP.  My server can configure itself within that /64 address space, with however many ipv6 addresses I want.  I want each of my proxy servers (running on the one host) to be able to use its own unique address within the allotted address space (don't care what the address is) and I want the prefix to change in case my ISP decides to hand out a different /64 prefix.  How would I configure this?

I'm setup right now to use netplan for networking configuration.  I like the lightweight nature of tinyproxy and it looks like it will do ipv6, but I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Several options here.

Ask your provider for a static allocation. IPv6 addresses are plentiful, so it should not be a big ask on a business account.

Choosing the host bits but letting the prefix be assigned to you has been called "tokenised idenfiers" in an IETF draft, inspired by a Solaris implementation. Linux does this with `ip token`.  Unfortunately, [support for setting the lower bits only seems to be lacking in netplan](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nplan/+bug/1737976).

If you relax the requirement of reachable from the Internet, you can generate yourself a unique local address subnet based on RFC 4193. Do whatever you want in this private space.

Comment: I could do a static allocation (this is a home lab, my ISP, Centurylink, does offer static allocations, but only ipv4, but looks like they use ipv6rd, so that gives a static ipv6 address also).  But for what that costs, I might as well get a cheap VPS.

Comment: Sorry about second post - accidentally posted.

What if I dropped netplan and configured systemd-networkd directly, making a virtual interface for each proxy?  Then the proxy servers could bind to virtual interfaces, rather than ip addresses (not sure tinyproxy can do that).

I don't need the proxy to be reachable from the internet, but it does need to be able to connect to the internet.

Comment: Assign multiple IP addresses to the interface however you like. You can have both static out of your ULA and automatic from your public on the same interface. You can try systemd.network  IPv6Token  if you are using SLAAC.